# Search Particular Offer in CLOB column storing XML data and update value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, clob, xmltype

First of all, I refered all the related question regarding manipulating XML tags via PL/SQL block but no luck

So, my requiremet is: I have a table with a CLOB column having data in XML form which is not in linear fashion

Please refer below example

```
<DATA>
    <TAGA>  
        <TAGB>
            <TAGC>
                <TAGD>
                    <TAG1>value1</TAG1>
                    <TAG2>value2</TAG2>
                </TAGD>

                **<MAINTAG>
                    <Name>student_id</Name>
                    <batch_id>2017</batch_id>
                    <Values>1001</Values>
                </MAINTAG>**

                **<MAINTAG>
                    <Name>student_type</Name>
                    <batch_id>2017</batch_id>
                    <Values>B</Values>
                </MAINTAG>**
            </TAGC>
        </TAGB>
    </TAGA>
</DATA>
```

Here, I want to update all the table rows with student_type value from 'B' to 'A' based on student id

But, here in both the tags , only batch_id is common, so need to first check batch_id and check corresponding student id

Here `<batch_id, student>` is will be unique pair like <2017,1001> , <2017,1002>

I tried via Merge into script but somehow unable to search for particular tag in whole XML data

Please refer below script

`Student_Temp` table with columns student_id , batch_id

```
declare
     v_rows number;
begin
    for i in 0..99
    loop
 merge into Student s
              using Student_Temp st on 
              (
                     st.student_id=s.student_id
                     and s.sub_id = 3008  
              )
              when matched then 
              update set s.general_data = replace(s.general_data,'<Values>A</Values>','<Values>B</Values>')
              where s.general_data like '%<Value>B</Value>%'
              and s.general_data like '%st.batch_id%' 
              and s.general_data like '%st.student_id%' 
              and s.general_data like '%student_type%';

    end loop;
end;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> here I want to update all the table rows with student_type value from
>   'B' to 'A' based on student id

When i see your update statment, it looks like you are trying to search for `A` and replace it with `B` and in your XML I dont see `A`, so you are not really finding the `Update` happening. See your update statement,

```
update set s.general_data = replace(s.general_data,'<Values>A</Values>','<Values>B</Values>')
```

Ideally it should be:

```
update set s.general_data = replace(s.general_data,'<Values>B</Values>','<Values>A</Values>')
```

See below a simple select with `replace` is working.

```
select col , replace(col,'<Values>B</Values>','<Values>A</Values>') replaced_data
from 
(select '<DATA>
    <TAGA>  
        <TAGB>
            <TAGC>
                <TAGD>
                    <TAG1>value1</TAG1>
                    <TAG2>value2</TAG2>
                </TAGD>

                **<MAINTAG>
                    <Name>student_id</Name>
                    <batch_id>2017</batch_id>
                    <Values>1001</Values>
                </MAINTAG>**

                **<MAINTAG>
                    <Name>student_type</Name>
                    <batch_id>2017</batch_id>
                    <Values>B</Values>
                </MAINTAG>**
            </TAGC>
        </TAGB>
    </TAGA>
</DATA>' col
from dual )
```

Also, i didnot understood the usage of for loop `for i in 0..99`. Not sure what is your intention but you are simply trying to `Merge` 100 time with same set of data. Looks redundant to me.

Comment: I have just posted part of XML file , But there may be case where TAG hierarchy won't be same , then above mentioned query won't work

Comment: @KiranChoudhary. Replace has nothing to do with tag hierarchy. You can try. According to me it should work in all case